# What is "Merchant Service Fee" also known as MSF?

Tags: word-meaning

What is "Merchant Service Fee" means? Is it only credit card fee or does it include shipping fee?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a technical term with a meaning that cannot be fully deduced from normal English rules.

Answer (score 1):

> Merchant Service Fee

is a fee that is charged for merchant services, and that can be *any* service.  It is generally associated with the fee a *seller* pays for using *credit card processing services* (back office), but this is because that is *how it's paid*.

The services offered usually include technical support, hardware (credit card readers), and payment processing amongst others.

Not sure why you are asking about *shipping fee* specifically.  If it is for something you have bought and the *seller* is charging to send it to you, in the US this is usually referred to as a

> handling charge

which is paid by the *end buyer* to the *seller*.